# Check if string starts with regex in ruby to match "[NATURAL NUMBER]"

Tags: ruby, regex

Suppose I have a following strings:

```
str1 = "[1] : blah blah blah"
str2 = "[2] : Something"
str3 = "Nothing"
```

I wrote a method `foo(str)` that takes a string as parameter and should return true if the string starts with "[DIGIT]" where digit can be any natural number (1,2,3,4...). So `str1` and `str2` should return true. `str3` should return false.

I can't figure out the regular expression to match `"[DIGIT]"`. `/[[\d]]/` was the best I could come up with, which doesn't work and only matches `"N]"`, misses the starting bracket. Try it [here](https://www.regex101.com/r/xI4cH4/1).

Currently the method looks like this:

```
def foo(str)
  str =~ /[[\d]]/
end
```

Comment: you have to escape the square brackets this `\[\d\]`  should match the digit within square bracket

Comment: Thanks you so much. It works :)

Comment: In future consider waiting longer before selecting an answer (> 2 hours, perhaps). Quick selections can discourage other answers and short-circuit those still preparing answers. The point is there's no rush.

Comment: There is more to it than that. If it must be at the start of a string you'd need to prepend `^`. Then the regex is gonna be `/^\[\d+\]/`

Comment: @sin, `^` and `$` are beginning-of and end-of-*line* anchors, whereas `\A` and `\z` are beginning-of and end-of-*string* anchors. While either can be used for one-line strings, I thinks it's clearer to use the latter in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this](http://rubular.com/r/sc772GcrPV), with slash:

```
$> irb
>> str1 = "[1] : blah blah blah"
>> str1[/\[\d\]/]
=> "[1]"
```

Use the `\` character to escape a character that has special meaning inside a regular expression.

Comment: You can just do `\[\d]` as well. I'd probably use `\[\d+]`

Comment: @NullUserException thanks, I'm not a regexp guru, just know about the special chars.

Comment: "...return true if the string *starts with*...". Escape `]` to suppress a warning message.

Comment: Hi just figured `\[\d\]` will not work for any number that is greater than 9. Eg it will not match for `"[10] : blah blah blah"`
Try this: http://rubular.com/r/Veyrxok6Nn

Comment: @dhrubo_moy you can fix your expression to `/\[\d+\]/` which allow more than one digit.From the rubular quick reference: _a+ One or more of a_

Comment: Thank you so so much. :D

Comment: dhrubo, you said the match must be at the beginning of the string. You therefore need to include a beginning-of-string "anchor" in the regex: `/\A\[\d\]/`, or `/\A\[\d+\]/` if multiple digits are permitted.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use a regex.

```
def starts_with_you_know_what(str)
  str[0] == '[' && '0123456789'.include?(str[1]) && str[2] == ']'
end

starts_with_you_know_what "[1] : blah blah blah" #=> true
starts_with_you_know_what "[2] : Something"      #=> true
starts_with_you_know_what "Nothing"              #=> false
```